# Multilevel Hierarchy in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am looking for the multi level recursive query where i try to find user group

### customer_hierarchy Table

```
customer_code | parent_code |
001           | 002         |
002           | 003         |
003           | 004         |
004           | 006         |
005           | 007         |
```

customer_table

```
--------------------------------
customer_code | customer_group |
001           | G1             |
002           | G2             |
003           | G3             |
004           | G4             |
001           | G5             |
```

Expected Result

```
--------------------------------
customer_code | customer_group |
001           | G1,G2,G3,G4    |
002           | G2,G3,G4       |
003           | G3,G4          |
004           | G2             |
```

i have tried using below query but not is working

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(customer_code SEPARATOR ',') FROM customer_hierarchy 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(parent_customer, @pv)) AS lv FROM customer_hierarchy 
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=0000000027) tmp
) a;
```

Comment: I am struggling to figure out what your SQL is trying to do. It appears to be using 0000000027 as a comma separated list of starting customers. But if so I would expect you to add to this list, not just replace it with each select. Normally what you are trying to do requires either using a different table design (nested set model normally) or using a MySQL custom function

Comment: Hello Kickstart, can you help mw with query